# Change pixel size of a pencil in Photoshop cc 2017

Tags: adobe-photoshop, pixels

How can I change the pixel size of a pencil in Photoshop cc 2017?

Here is my program opened:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you do not want to use brush instead of pencil?

Comment: @RomeoNinov, I am going to do a pixel art. I suppose I won`t be able to do that with brush.

Comment: You can create brush really small :)

Answer (score 0):

In your image I see that Photoshop Options bar is not there. Open the Window menu and select Options.

Selecting the Pencil tool you will be able to choose, in the Options bar, the Pencil size and hardness.